# How to change values whilie moving the circles on range-seek-bar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm using https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/"  seek bar . it has double circles .

the problem is this ,It has only on method setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener and it can't get the values while I pressing down the circle and moving it .

It only return values when I drop the circle .

How can I return the values while I pressing down the circle and moving it ?

thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Call `setNotifyWhenDragging(true)` and use `setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(listener)` to be notified while the user is dragging the selectors.